# LaTeX: insert two rotated pages on one page

Tags: pdf, rotation, latex, include

I have a pdf file with several pages and want to include them in my LaTeX file.

```
\includepdf[pages=-, angle=90, scale=0.95]{folder/file.pdf}
```

I want to get two pages of my pdf file on every LaTeX page, but my code above only inserts one rotated page on each page. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=1-10, angle=90, scale=0.95,nup=1x2]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @KJ It would have been quicker if there had been a mwe. Typing all these `\documentclass` and stuff really slows one down :)

Comment: @KJ ... and I used example-image-duck at first, but the orientation is wrong. I needed something in portrait ...

Comment: @KJ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samcarter/tikzducks/main/duckpond/Leonardo.svg

Comment: Thank you! How do I change the order of the two pages? I want to read from left side to right side ;-)

Comment: @user15072994 turn them in the other direction or  use `\includepdf[pages=1-10,  scale=0.95,nup=1x2,landscape]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
`